# Laravel obtener unico elemento de una colección pero que sea el minimo de acuerdo al precio

Tags: php

Tengo la siguiente colección:

```
[
{
"product_id":"0a55da20-4133-11ea-9855-d5cc9141e87f",
"seller_id":"dad255b0-4132-11ea-af4f-e35b2a7d9852",
"sale_price":1560,
"auction_price":1300,
"size":9,
"typesize":"Hombre",
"condition":"nuevo",
"image":"http://legit.mx/images/Jordan_1_Retro_High_Homage_To_Home_(Non_numbered)/",
"model_name":"Jordan 1 Retro High Homage To Home (Non-numbered)",
"release_date":"2018-05-19",
"sku":"11111",
"retail_price":"111",
"color":"WHITE/CORE BLACK/RED"
},
{
"product_id":"2162c720-46f0-11ea-9424-5f8a7104fef3",
"seller_id":"dad255b0-4132-11ea-af4f-e35b2a7d9852",
"sale_price":1350,
"auction_price":1000,
"size":9,
"typesize":"Hombre",
"condition":"nuevo",
"image":"http://legit.mx/images/Jordan_1_Retro_High_Homage_To_Home_(Non_numbered)/",
"model_name":"Jordan 1 Retro High Homage To Home (Non-numbered)",
"release_date":"2018-05-19",
"sku":"11111",
"retail_price":"111",
"color":"WHITE/CORE BLACK/RED"
},
{
"product_id":"5c52d5d0-414d-11ea-981d-bb00234dcbbd",
"seller_id":"dd79d190-413d-11ea-ad1e-d598a1ff37de",
"sale_price":2532,
"auction_price":2200,
"size":9,
"typesize":"Hombre",
"condition":"nuevo",
"image":"http://legit.mx/images/Jordan_1_Retro_High_Homage_To_Home_(Non_numbered)/",
"model_name":"Jordan 1 Retro High Homage To Home (Non-numbered)",
"release_date":"2018-05-19",
"sku":"11111",
"retail_price":"111",
"color":"WHITE/CORE BLACK/RED"
},
{
"product_id":"ecec1c40-415c-11ea-811d-c36c38400b2e",
"seller_id":"dad255b0-4132-11ea-af4f-e35b2a7d9852",
"sale_price":2300,
"auction_price":1800,
"size":10.5,
"typesize":"Mujer",
"condition":"nuevo",
"image":"http://legit.mx/images/Jordan_1_Retro_High_Homage_To_Home_(Non_numbered)/",
"model_name":"Jordan 1 Retro High Homage To Home (Non-numbered)",
"release_date":"2018-05-19",
"sku":"11111",
"retail_price":"111",
"color":"WHITE/CORE BLACK/RED"
}
]
```

Quisiera obtener el objeto con el precio minimo (sale_price) de cada producto (talla), es decir, para este ejercicio solo me debe obtener 2 objectos que corresponden al id "2162c720-46f0-11ea-9424-5f8a7104fef3" y el "ecec1c40-415c-11ea-811d-c36c38400b2e", para la colección he utilizado el método "unique" y si me obtiene el producto único para cada talla pero no es la talla con el precio minimo, ¿Cómo podría hacer esto?

---

Mi codigo es:

```
public function getAllSizesToProduct($id){
        $products = Product::with(['user', 'models', 'models.image', 'priceproduct', 'size', 'typesize', 'condition'])
            ->where('models_id', $id)->get();
        if($products->count() > 0){
            // Array para los productos con el menor precio de cada modelo

            $results = collect();
            foreach ($products as $product) {
                $results->add($this->addArrayToObjectProduct($product));
            }

            $unique = $results->unique('size');

            return response()->json($unique, 200);
        }else{
            $error = [
                'error' => 'No hay productos disponibles para su venta.'
            ];
            return response()->json($error, 404);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muchas gracias miguel, finalmente mi código quedó así con algunas modificaciones:

```
public function getAllSizesToProduct($id){
    $products = Product::with(['user', 'models', 'models.image', 'priceproduct', 'size', 'typesize', 'condition'])
        ->where('models_id', $id)->get();
    if($products->count() > 0){
        // Array para los productos con el menor precio de cada modelo

        $results = collect();
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            // Depurar información que no se requiere y dejar solo la necesaria
            $results->add($this->addArrayToObjectProduct($product));
        }
        // Se agrupan la información por el tamaño
        $sizes = $results->groupBy('size')->toArray();
        //$mins = []; // Array para almacenar los minimos encontrados
        $resultsMin = collect(); // Almacenar los objetos con precio minimo para cada talla
        // Recorremos los grupos
        foreach($sizes as $size) {
            // Valor minimo encontrado para el grupo actual
            $minPrice = collect($size)->min('sale_price');
            //$mins[] = $minPrice;
            // Recorremos los objetos de cada grupo
            foreach($size as $currentSize){
                // Comparar el precio de cada objeto para encontrar el que coincide con el minimo encontrado
                if($minPrice == $currentSize['sale_price']){
                    // almaceno el producto encontrado en la colección 
                    $resultsMin->add($currentSize);
                }
            }
        }
        return response()->json($resultsMin, 200);
    }else{
        $error = [
            'error' => 'No hay productos disponibles para su venta.'
        ];
        return response()->json($error, 404);
    }
}
```

Si alguien tiene alguna manera mas eficaz de realizarlo, mucho agradeceré el apoyo que me puedan brindar.

Answer (score 0):

Primero recesitas agruparlos por talla y despues calcular el min. En el ejemplo $tu_collecion seria la colleción que muestras como ejemplo. Salvo que la tengas ya como Laravel collection, en ese caso te puedes ahorrar la llamada al metodo collect.

```
$collection = collect($tu_collecion);
$sizes = $collection->groupBy('size')->toArray();
$mins = [];    
foreach($sizes as $size) {
   $mins[] = array_filter($size, function($size_item) {
      return $size_item == collect($size)->min('sale_price');
   }
}
```

Mas info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#available-methods

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo implementaré y te comento que tal me va.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias, me funciona, pero, solo me regresa los montos minimos y yo quiero la información completa de cada objeto que encontró como minimo.

Comment: Actualizada, simplemente debes filtrar el array sizes según el precio mínimo.

Comment: @AlfredoAngelesSolis no olvides que puedes marcar como aceptada alguna de las respuestas y opcionalmente darle un +1, de este modo los demás sabremos que tu duda ha sido resuelta